# Table 1 Group Variables

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to group variables in table1().
I want to mimic "Desired layout of Table1", and I am currently working with "Generated Table1 from `table1()` function".

More specifically, I want to mimic the rows of Donor and Recipients (the red drawings of g1 and g2 referring to the rows I want to produce).

[image: Generated Table1 from table1() function]

[image: Desired layout of Table1]

Is this something that involves manipulating the data before using `table1()` or is there an argument in `table1()` that already does this for me.

I've tried using a key to separate Donors and Recipients but that didn't prove useful. I've tried using the strata argument to see if I can stratify the data by rows and that led no where. I would really appreciate help on this.

This is what I have so far.

```
library(table1)

label(t1data$`Recipient Age`) <- "Age, y"
label(t1data$`Recipient Sex`) <- "Sex"
label(t1data$`Recipient Race`) <- "Race"
label(t1data$`Recipient Ethnicity`) <- "Ethnicity"
 
label(t1data$`Donor Age`) <- "Age, y"
label(t1data$`Donor Gender`) <- "Sex"
label(t1data$`Donor Race`) <- "Race"

label(t1data$`Donor Ethnicity`) <- "Ethnicity"
table1( ~ `Recipient Age` + `Recipient Sex` + `Recipient Ethnicity` + `Recipient Race` +
          `Donor Age` + `Donor Gender` + `Donor Ethnicity` + `Donor Race` | Status, data = t1data, overall = FALSE, rowlabelhead = "Demographics")
```